# Updating one dataframe with the most recent data from a separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to update a dataframe of positions with the prices stored in a separate data frames. I would like to put the most recent price in the column "last_price" and the data of that price in column "last_date".

```
import datetime
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df_portfolio = pd.DataFrame({ 'amount' : np.random.randint(low=0, high=10,     size=(4)),
                    'timestamp' : pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                    'exch' : pd.Categorical(["e1","e1","e2","e2"]),
                    'token' : pd.Categorical(["BTC","ETH","ETH","LTC"])
               })

df_ETH_price = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ('2018-08-11','2018-08-12','2018-08-13'),
    'price' : (322.11,319.57,286.50)    
    })

df_portfolio['last_price'] = np.nan
df_portfolio['last_date'] = "?"

print(df_portfolio)
print (df_ETH_price)
```

The expected results would be as follows:

```
   amount exch  timestamp token  last_price last_date
0       7   e1 2013-01-02   BTC         NaN         ?
1       4   e1 2013-01-02   ETH         286.50      2018-08-13
2       2   e2 2013-01-02   ETH         286.50      2018-08-13
3       9   e2 2013-01-02   LTC         NaN         ?
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a flag in your price tracking dataframes so it's obvious which coin is being talked about:

```
m = df_ETH_price.assign(token='ETH').tail(1)
```

Then merge:

```
df_portfolio.merge(
    m, how='outer'
).rename(columns={'date': 'last_date', 'price': 'last_price'})
```

```
   amount  timestamp exch token   last_date  last_price
0       2 2013-01-02   e1   BTC         NaN         NaN
1       0 2013-01-02   e1   ETH  2018-08-13       286.5
2       3 2013-01-02   e2   ETH  2018-08-13       286.5
3       7 2013-01-02   e2   LTC         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

First create a dataframe from the latest row in `df_ETH_price`:

```
df_ETH_price['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_ETH_price['date'])
latest = df_ETH_price.assign(token='ETH').sort_values('date', ascending=False).head(1)

print(latest)

        date  price token
2 2018-08-13  286.5   ETH
```

Then merge with `df_portfolio`:

```
res = pd.merge(df_portfolio, latest, how='left')

print(res)

   amount exch  timestamp token       date  price
0       1   e1 2013-01-02   BTC        NaT    NaN
1       3   e1 2013-01-02   ETH 2018-08-13  286.5
2       6   e2 2013-01-02   ETH 2018-08-13  286.5
3       0   e2 2013-01-02   LTC        NaT    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

`.combine_first` is a good way to update values in a `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd

# Make datetime
df_ETH_price['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_ETH_price.date)

# Find the last valid row + tidy up naming for the join.
df_last = (df_ETH_price.loc[[df_ETH_price.date.idxmax()]]
              .add_prefix('last_')
              .assign(token='ETH')
              .set_index('token'))

df_portfolio = df_last.combine_first(df_portfolio.set_index('token')).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  token  amount  timestamp exch  last_date  last_price
0   BTC       3 2013-01-02   e1        NaT         NaN
1   ETH       6 2013-01-02   e1 2018-08-13       286.5
2   ETH       4 2013-01-02   e2 2018-08-13       286.5
3   LTC       8 2013-01-02   e2        NaT         NaN
```

If you have multiple DataFrames you need to do this for, I'd consider something like:

```
def update_price(df_port, df, token):
    df_last = (df.loc[[df.date.idxmax()]]
              .add_prefix('last_')
              .assign(token=token)
              .set_index('token'))

    return df_last.combine_first(df_port.set_index('token')).reset_index()
```

then you can simply do something like:

```
df_LTC_price = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ('2018-08-11','2018-08-12','2018-08-13'),
    'price' : (322.11,319.57,280.50)    
    })

df_portfolio = update_price(df_portfolio, df_ETH_price, 'ETH')
df_portfolio = update_price(df_portfolio, df_LTC_price, 'LTC')
```

Output:

```
  token  amount exch  last_date  last_price  timestamp
0   BTC     6.0   e1        NaT         NaN 2013-01-02
1   ETH     1.0   e1 2018-08-13       286.5 2013-01-02
2   ETH     3.0   e2 2018-08-13       286.5 2013-01-02
3   LTC     3.0   e2 2018-08-13       280.5 2013-01-02
```

Because `.combine_first` gives priority to `df_last` you can even use it to update `df_portfolio` with new data for the same `token` if you receive more data tomorrow for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `df_ETH_price` continues to be in chronological order:

```
latest_ETH = df_ETH_price.iloc[-1]
df_portfolio.loc[df_portfolio['token'] == 'ETH', 'last_price'] = latest_ETH.price
df_portfolio.loc[df_portfolio['token'] == 'ETH', 'last_date'] = latest_ETH.date
```